# Azure DevOps - Pipelines checkout

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I am trying to solve a problem where I can't find the right documentation for the problem that I have.

At the moment, in my project, I am using Azure DevOps pipelines to build and deploy a simples code in a function. What I am trying to approach is to have multiple stages doing something concrete.

**Example of the pipeline**

```yaml
Stage 1: Validation of code (check style, guidelines, etc.)  
Stage 2: Tests
  - Job1: Unit Tests
  - Job2: Integration Tests
Stage 3: Deployment to the cloud
Stage 4: Function tests against the deployment done on Stage 3.
```

**Problem**

As you may know, when you do different stages, the pipelines run into different slaves, which means that will apply the git checkout in all of them. What I am trying to make is to avoid this checkouts and only make one single checkout on the first stage and use the checkout of the first stage for the rest (the code is the same..)

Do you have any clue what I am missing here? I know that I can do this process in a single stage with all steps/jobs inside but I want to split this in different stages to make sure that each stage has it own responsability.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where your agents run, if the agents are self-hosted, you can of course use a common location and avoid checking out the self repo. With hosted agents, I don't think you can do this using the stage concept in azure pipelines, stages have specific semantics which do not map to your desired outcome AFAIK. There are other ways to split the responsibilities without insisting on using azure pipeline stages. It depends on what you want to achieve with this splitting of responsibilities;

If you simply want to logically partition the pipeline there are alternatives e.g. templates which will allow you to separate the partitions into files which can be maintained separately, if that would satisfy your requirement for separation of responsibilities. They can even be separated into different repositories like in the example below, of course they can also reside in the same repository.

An example I use for caching and restoring dependencies for C++ projects using a common repository.

```
- checkout: DevOpsScripts

    - template: up-restore.yml@DevOpsScripts
      parameters:
        CachePath: $(updepsCache)
        CacheKeyPrefix: 'updeps | "$(Agent.OS)"'
        DependenciesManifest: $(updepsPrefix)$(osSuffix).json
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in order to accomplish that you should have a custom agent on which you can have a folder to store the code for example C:\code. Then you can checkout the repository on this code path and disable checkout on the next stages.

You can disable `checkout` on the job inside your stage.

```
  - job: DeployCode
    displayName: Deploy code
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - script: echo deploying code
      displayName: deploy code
```

[image: disable checkout]

In order to checkout on a specific directory on your self hosted agent you should:

```
- checkout: self
  clean: true
  path: C:\code
```